# ActiveX Combobox doesn't close automatically

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I have an `ActiveX` `Combobox` in one of my main sheet which control/update a series of charts.

```
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_GotFocus()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Me.cmBoxSelect
       .List = Array("Grand Total", "Prod1", "Prod2", "Prod3", "Prod4", "Prod5")
       .ListRows = 6
       .DropDown
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmBoxSelect_Change()
     'series of codes which manipulates the charts, based on selection...

End Sub
```

I noticed that when I click the `ComboBox` and select one of its content, it leaves a blue highlight on the selection. So to prevent that, I added:

```
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_DropButtonClick()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveCell.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It successfully removed the highlight.

However, it has a weird drawback. `cmbSelect` doesn't close automatically once user **didn't** select anything (once the combobox is active and the user click any cell in the sheet, it doesn't close out). It was working before I added the `DropButtonClick` event.

Did I missed anything or any wrong steps above? Thanks for your inputs!

**EDIT#1**

Seems I already found a solution by trial and error. I only added a blank Label and select it to remove the focus out of the ComboBox whenever there is a change. I also changed the `DropButtonClick` to `LostFocus`.

```
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_GotFocus()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Me.cmBoxSelect
       .List = Array("Grand Total", "Prod1", "Prod2", "Prod3", "Prod4", "Prod5")
       .ListRows = 6
       .DropDown
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmBoxSelect_LostFocus()
    ActiveCell.Select
End Sub

Private Sub cmBoxSelect_Change()
     'series of codes which manipulates the charts, based on selection...

     Me.Label1.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: It's hard to replicate your problem. Is there a reason you are messing around with the screenUpdating application?

Comment: Because I noticed that there's a little effect (on speed) when I turned the screenupdating off/on on the `GotFocus`. Not sure why tho.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the SelLength to 0 in multiple events to avoid highlighting:

so:

```
Me.cmBoxSelect.SelLength = 0
```

in:

```
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_LostFocus()
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_DropButtonClick()
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_Change()
Private Sub cmBoxSelect_GotFocus()
```

(you could add also Me.cmBoxSelect.SelStart = 0 )

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this:
Not Event-triggered by a change, but by the dropbuttonclick

```
Private Sub changingComboBox(String s)


     'series of codes which manipulates the charts, based on selection...

End Sub

Private Sub cmBoxSelect_DropButtonClick()
    Dim s As String
    s = cmBoxSelect.SelText

    If (cmBoxSelect.SelText = cmBoxSelect.Value) Then

        cmBoxSelect.Value = ""
        cmBoxSelect.Value = s

    Else

        call changingComboBox(cmBoxSelect.Value)

    End If

End Sub
```

How about that ?